# html pdf Invoice Width and height Issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, layout

My code working fine,but i have an issue in page layout.When i print this file it provide the print in two pages,i want print on one page.And other issue is i want to convert this invoice into pdf directly.Please correct my own code according to my need i will be highly thankful to you. Looking positive response.

```js
$('#printInvoice').click(function(){
            Popup($('.invoice')[0].outerHTML);
            function Popup(data) 
            {
                window.print();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

```css
 #invoice{
    padding: 30px;
}

.invoice {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 680px;
    padding: 15px
}

.invoice header {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3989c6
}

.invoice .company-details {
    text-align: right
}

.invoice .company-details .name {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.invoice .contacts {
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

.invoice .invoice-to {
    text-align: left
}

.invoice .invoice-to .to {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.invoice .invoice-details {
    text-align: right
}

.invoice .invoice-details .invoice-id {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #3989c6
}

.invoice main {
    padding-bottom: 50px
}

.invoice main .thanks {
    margin-top: -100px;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 50px
}

.invoice main .notices {
    padding-left: 6px;
    border-left: 6px solid #3989c6
}

.invoice main .notices .notice {
    font-size: 1.2em
}

.invoice table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

.invoice table td,.invoice table th {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff
}

.invoice table th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px
}

.invoice table td h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3989c6;
    font-size: 1.2em
}

.invoice table .qty,.invoice table .total,.invoice table .unit {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.2em
}

.invoice table .no {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    background: #3989c6
}

.invoice table .unit {
    background: #ddd
}

.invoice table .total {
    background: #3989c6;
    color: #fff
}

.invoice table tbody tr:last-child td {
    border: none
}

.invoice table tfoot td {
    background: 0 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa
}

.invoice table tfoot tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none
}

.invoice table tfoot tr:last-child td {
    color: #3989c6;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    border-top: 1px solid #3989c6
}

.invoice table tfoot tr td:first-child {
    border: none
}

.invoice footer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 8px 0
}

@media print {
    .invoice {
        font-size: 11px!important;
        overflow: hidden!important
    }

    .invoice footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        page-break-after: always
    }

    .invoice>div:last-child {
        page-break-before: always
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="invoice">

    <div class="toolbar hidden-print">
        <div class="text-right">
            <button id="printInvoice" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Export as PDF</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="invoice overflow-auto">
        <div style="min-width: 600px">
            <header>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://lobianijs.com">
                            <img src="../img/logo_nbdp_sme.png" width="136" height="103" data-holder-rendered="true" />
                            </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col company-details">
                        <h2 class="name">
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://lobianijs.com">
                            Trainer Name
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                        <div>Trainer Experties</div>
                        <div>Trainer Qualification</div>
                        <div>Training type</div>
                        <div>Partner Organization (If any)</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div class="row contacts">
                    <div class="col invoice-to">
                        <div class="text-gray-light">Pre Event ID</div>
                        <h2 class="to">Training Topic</h2>
                        <div class="address">Venue,City,Province </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col invoice-details">
                        <h1 class="invoice-id">Pre Event Budget</h1>
                        <div class="date">Pre Event Date</div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered mb-0" >
                   <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Heads of Expenses</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Unit</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold"># of Units</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Unit Cost (Rs.)</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Maximum Expense</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Reference Note</th>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Trainer & Participant Expenses</b></td> 
                                
                                
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Trainer Fee (Mr. <?php echo $TrainerName; ?>)</td> 
                                <td>Trainer Fee</td>
                                <td>Trainer Fee</td>
                                <td>Trainer Fee</td>
                                <td>Trainer Fee</td>
                                <td>Trainer Fee</td>    
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Pay Per Participant Expenses</td> 
                                <td>Pay Per</td>
                                <td>Pay Per</td>
                                <td>Pay Per</td>
                                <td>Pay Per</td>
                                <td>Pay Per</td>    
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td> 
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>Total: </b></td>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td></td>   
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><div align="left" style="font-size:13px">Travelling Expenses </div></th>
                        <th colspan="5" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Air Ticket</td> 
                                <td>Air</td>
                                <td>Air</td>
                                <td>Air</td>
                                <td>Air</td>
                                <td>Air</td>
                                
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Trainer travel / Fuel Expense</td> 
                                <td>Trainer</td>
                                <td>Trainer</td>
                                <td>Trainer</td>
                                <td>Trainer</td>
                                <td>Trainer</td>    
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Rent a Car</td> 
                                <td>Rent</td>
                                <td>Rent</td>
                                <td>Rent</td>
                                <td>Rent</td>
                                <td>Rent</td>   
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Accommodation</td> 
                                <td>Accommodation</td>
                                <td>Accommodation</td>
                                <td>Accommodation</td>
                                <td>Accommodation</td>
                                <td>Accommodation</td>  
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td></td> 
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>Total: </b></td>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td></td>   
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><div align="left" style="font-size:13px">Venue Charges </div></th>
                        <th colspan="5" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Hall Rent</td> 
                                <td>Hall</td>
                                <td>Hall</td>
                                <td>Hall</td>
                                <td>Hall</td>
                                <td>Hall</td>
                                
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lunch & Tea</td> 
                                <td>Lunch</td>
                                <td>Lunch</td>
                                <td>Lunch</td>
                                <td>Lunch</td>
                                <td>Lunch</td>  
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td> 
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>Total: </b></td>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td></td>   
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        
                        
                        
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><div align="left" style="font-size:13px">Marketing & Awareness </div></th>
                        <th colspan="5" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>News Paper Ad</td> 
                                <td>News</td>
                                <td>News</td>
                                <td>News</td>
                                <td>News</td>
                                <td>News</td>
                                
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Social Media Marketing Compaign</td> 
                                <td>Social</td>
                                <td>Social</td>
                                <td>Social</td>
                                <td>Social</td>
                                <td>Social</td> 
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Brochure / Handouts</td> 
                                <td>Brochure</td>
                                <td>Brochure</td>
                                <td>Brochure</td>
                                <td>Brochure</td>
                                <td>Brochure</td>   
                            </tr>
                            
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Postage</td> 
                                <td>Postage</td>
                                <td>Postage</td>
                                <td>Postage</td>
                                <td>Postage</td>
                                <td>Postage</td>    
                            </tr>
                            
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td></td> 
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>Total:</b></td>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td></td>   
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        
                        
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><div align="left" style="font-size:13px">Event Related Expenses </div></th>
                        <th colspan="5" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Banner and Backdrop</td> 
                                <td>Banner</td>
                                <td>Banner</td>
                                <td>Banner</td>
                                <td>Banner</td>
                                <td>Banner</td>
                                
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Standees</td> 
                                <td>Standees</td>
                                <td>Standees</td>
                                <td>Standees</td>
                                <td>Standees</td>
                                <td>Standees</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Training Material/Stationery</td> 
                                <td>Stationery</td>
                                <td>Stationery</td>
                                <td>Stationery</td>
                                <td>Stationery</td>
                                <td>Stationery</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Certificate & Printing</td> 
                                <td>Printing</td>
                                <td>Printing</td>
                                <td>Printing</td>
                                <td>Printing</td>
                                <td>Printing</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Photographs / Media Coverage</td> 
                                <td>Photographs</td>
                                <td>Photographs</td>
                                <td>Photographs</td>
                                <td>Photographs</td>
                                <td>Photographs</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Event Related Support</td> 
                                <td>Event</td>
                                <td>Event</td>
                                <td>Event</td>
                                <td>Event</td>
                                <td>Event</td>
                            </tr>
        
                            <tr>
                               <td></td> 
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>Event Related Expense:</b></td>
                                <td><b>Related</b></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                               <td></td> 
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>Total Expense:</b></td>
                                <td><b>Total</b></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      
                      
                      <table class="table table-bordered mb-0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Heads of Expenses</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Unit</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold"># of Unit</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Unit Cost</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Total (Rs.)</th>
                                <th class="text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Reference Note</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Participants</td>
                                <td>Participants</td> 
                                <td>Participants</td>
                                <td>Participants</td>
                                <td>Participants</td>
                                <td>Participants</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>SMEDA Contribution</td>
                                <td>SMEDA</td> 
                                <td>SMEDA</td> 
                                <td>SMEDA</td> 
                                <td>SMEDA</td> 
                                <td>SMEDA</td> 
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" align="left"  scope="row">Total Receipt</td> 
                                <td><b>Total Receipt</b></td>
                                <td></td>   
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" align="left">Net Income</td> 
                                <td><b>Net Income</b></td>
                                <td></td>   
                            </tr>
                            
                            </tbody>
                </table>
               
            </main>
          
        </div>
        <!--DO NOT DELETE THIS div. IT is responsible for showing footer always at the bottom-->
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `width: 19cm;` in CSS to exactly get A4 or whatever format you want. Then you need to deactivate the printing margins in your browser's printing settings. For PDF generation you're better off if you do it on the server; I use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) for this.

Comment: where i set width: 19cm please mention

Comment: Something like `#invoice { width: 19cm; padding: 1cm; }` would be a start. Basic CSS, you know?